# Shell pipeline does not function with dig

Tags: bash, shell, pipeline, dig

.
This might be a particularly stupid question, but I am new to shell scripting. Sorry for that!

I am trying to use the pipeline (to pass the output of the first command to the second one as its input parameter).

```
cat filename.csv | nslookup
```

functions as I expected, calls nslookup for every line in the file. However, same thing doesn't work for dig

```
cat filename.csv | dig
```

says

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>>
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that `dig` reads from stdin. Rather,

> The -f option makes dig operate in batch mode by reading a list of
>   lookup requests to process from the file filename. The file contains a
>   number of queries, one per line. Each entry in the file should be
>   organized in the same way they
>          would be presented as queries to dig using the command-line interface.

(from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig))

Note as an aside that your nslookup example qualifies for [this award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) (!) and could be rewritten as

```
nslookup < filename.csv
```

to achieve the same.

Comment: That wasn't my eternal goal actually. I am trying to send some parallel / asynchronous requests. I thought I have to learn how to use the | first (in order to pass the parameters to xargs or parallel). Thanks a lot for your help, I really like my award :)

Comment: No problem. I have won that award numerous times in the past.